# Sticky table header under postion:fixed and top:0 element (sticky header)

Tags: html, css

I can do **sticky headers** for table like this:

```
th {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Problem is that, I try to use this in layout where I already have one element positioned to top. How should the table headers be aligned in away that `top:0` corresponds to the bottom of header (which is in `top=0` position) ? I don't want to use value for alignment, as the header is higher and lower in different views..

Comment: can you add enough code to reproduce your issue . sticky can be tricky if you do not fully understand how it works. As it is , your question is unclear about the real context.(where stands the table, which element scrolls, if any other sticky elements and where they are standing in the flow , etc...) Without a clear question demonstrating your issue, you'll get downvotes and surely see your question closed, then deleted. However, Welcome on SO that runs with a few rules ;)

Comment: If the element which is already positioned at top has a fixed height then use `top: //heightOfElement`.